# Oracle VirtualBox - cannot import image

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

Before I was able on Win10 to import the same image (created on VirtualBox 6 on linux machine) but now I'm not able to import it any more in VirtualBox v6.0.8 (on WIndows 10 machine). I get the error message:

```
Failed to import appliance C:\Users\sbrbot\Downloads\mywebapp.ova

Result Code: E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057)
```

The image file (mywebapp.ova) is not corrupted because I can import it into VirtualBox v5.2 (interesting, it was created on VBox6 and can import on VBox5.2 but not VBox6.0.8)

What could be the problem?

Comment: I know this is a bit of an old question, did you ever figure it out? Often this error is caused by low disk space but I have the same problem and I have disk space

Comment: No, I didn't figure it out, I gave up. Probably some bug that will be resolven in some of next releases.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your logs, tipically "C:\Users\<%Username%>\.VirtualBox\VBoxSVC.log". Maybe you can found there further information. In my case I found a message like this:

```
00:02:36.889818 createImport ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004) aIID={ad47ad09-787b-44ab-b343-a082a3f2dfb1} aComponent={MediumWrap} aText={Could not create the imported medium 'F:\Data\User\Linux\VMLinux\OracleLinux\OracleLinux-disk001.vdi'.
00:02:36.889872 createImport VMDK: Compressed image is corrupted 'C:\Users\User\OracleLinux-disk001.vmdk' (VERR_ZIP_CORRUPTED)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=-22001
```

I downloaded the same image and then imported again without any error.